# Changing primary Google email

Tags: blogger, google-account

I was trying to make a new blog at blogger.com with a new email.
So I registered for a new one not knowing that I was already logged into mine.
Now the email I wanted to associate with the new blog is part of my old blog. I need that email name for my new one as it's a project with my friends.
It's become my primary email.

How do I change that or rename it so that I can make the email name available for my new blog?

Answer (score 1):

I just want see if I'm understanding your correctly.  From your post, I think that what has happened is:

- You wanted to make newBlog.blogspot.com, and have it owned by
  newEmail@gmail.com
- But you accidentally created it while you were logged on with
  oldEmail@gmail.com, instead of newEmail@gmail.com

If that's right, then you need to transfer the ownership of newBlog.blogspot.com  from the old to the new accounts.

If you do it now, before newBlog.blogspot.com has many features set up, then it's quite simple:

- invite the new account to become an author
- once the invitation has been accepted, promote it to become an administrator
- then use the new account to remove the old account's administrator rights.   (this step may be optional - you could find it useful to leave your own account with rights, too)

Ideally use two different browsers (eg Chrome and Firefox) while you are doing this:  log in to each account with a different browser.

If what I described isn't quite what happened, then you may need to modify the procedure a little, to achieve what you want.

(I've written a post about options for letting other people write to your blog, which you may find helpful:    http://blogger-hints-and-tips.blogspot.com/2012/01/letting-other-people-write-in-your-blog.html   )